# What is the distribution of sum of a Gaussian and a Rayleigh distributed independent r.v.?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $Z=X+Y$; where $X\sim \mathscr N(0,\sigma^2_1)$ i.e. a Gaussian random variable and $Y$ follows the Rayleigh  distribution:
$$
f_Y(y) =  \frac{y}{\sigma^2_2}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma^2_2}\right) \mathbf{1}_{y \geqslant 0}
$$ 
What will be the distribution of $Z$?

Comment: Would you like to know if the distribution of $x+y$ belongs to a known class of distributions? Also: are $x,y$ independent?

Answer (score 2):

The probability density function for $Z$, $f_Z(z)$ is obtained as a convolution of $f_X$ and $f_Y$, assuming $X$ and $Y$ are *independent*:
$$
    f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^\infty f_Y(y) f_X(z-y) \mathrm{d} y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_1 \sigma_2^2} \int_0^\infty y \exp\left( -\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma_2^2}\right) \exp\left( - \frac{(z-y)^2}{2 \sigma_1^2} \right) \mathrm{d} y
$$
Evaluation of this integral is straightforward, but tedious, and is done via integration by parts, with the following result:
$$
 f_Z(z) =  \frac{\sigma_2 z}{\left(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2\right)^{3/2}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{z^2}{2 \left(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2\right)}} \Phi\left( \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1} \frac{ z}{ \sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}}\right) + \frac{\sigma_1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \left(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2\right)} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{z^2}{2 \sigma_1^2}}
$$
where $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal random variable.

Comment: Any reference please? (Assuming that you didn't need to do it by hand)

Comment: I did it manually or with Mathematica. Steps are: combine two exponents and complete the square, then integrate by parts. It is very straightforward, but tedious.

Comment: Yup, thanks! I was expecting a magical tool from you other than your brain. It seems there is nothing like it. (ICYDK, Thats just a bit of appreciation) :)

Comment: @Sasha -- A detailed step by step solution would be greatly appreciated, as this question arises all the time in wireless communications. It is one of the most fundamental distributions in wireless communications, and being able to derive this is incredibly important.

Comment: I just found an application for mechanical as well. This is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is

$$\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{|x|}{\sigma_w \sigma_h} \right)}{2 \sigma_w \sigma_h}$$

Comment: this is the correct answer

Comment: Please use LaTeX for math. And don't comment on your own answers to say they are right.