# What is the distribution of sum of a Gaussian and and 2 r.v. Rayleigh distributed?

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

Let $Z=X+Y+W$;

where $X∼N(0,σ_1^2)$ i.e. a Gaussian random variable and Y and W follow the Rayleigh distribution:

$f_w(w)=\frac{w}{σ_2^2} . exp(−\frac{w^2}{2σ_2^2})$, 
$y\ge0$

What will be the distribution of Z, assuming X,Y and W indipendent?

I read another post very similar in this forum:
[What is the distribution of sum of a Gaussian and a Rayleigh distributed independent r.v.?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143056/what-is-the-distribution-of-sum-of-a-gaussian-and-a-rayleigh-distributed-indepen)

and I would only have the confirmation that I could achieve the $Z$'s pdf applying two times the convolution rule.
I mean first convolution between $f_y$ and $f_w$, then $f_{yw}$ against $f_x$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should add that you assume that all are independent? Nor not?

Comment: Yes, thanks. X,Y and W are independent.

Comment: May I resume this post in order to see if someone could give any indication? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Explicit form of the PDF/CDF is difficult to derive. However, the characteristic function of Z can be easily derived from the characteristic functions of X and Y resp. W.

Here we have 
$$\mathrm{cf}_X(t) = \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2_1 t^2),$$
and
$$\mathrm{cf}_Y(t) = \mathrm{cf}_W(t) = \ _1F_1\left(1;\frac{1}{2};- \frac{\sigma^2_2}{2}t^2\right) +\sqrt{2}\sigma_2 i t \,_1F_1\left(\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2};- \frac{\sigma^2_2}{2}t^2\right).$$
Hence, 
$$\mathrm{cf}_Z(t) = \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2_1 t^2)\left(_1F_1\left(1;\frac{1}{2};- \frac{\sigma^2_2}{2}t^2\right) + \sqrt{2}\sigma_2 i t\, _1F_1\left(\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2};- \frac{\sigma^2_2}{2}t^2\right) \right)^2.$$
Analytical inversion of this characteristic function can be difficult. However, numerical inversion is possible, and can be easily performed, e.g. by using the [CharFunTool](https://github.com/witkovsky/CharFunTool) (the Characteristic Functions Toolbox in MATLAB).